# Fixed panel at the bottom of the screen

Tags: xaml, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

Hi I'm trying to have two floating buttons at the bottom of the screen. Right now I implement the following code:

```
<ScrollViewer>
<RelativePanel>
// Main Content here
<StackPanel RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" >Two buttons appears at the bottom of the PAGE (not screen)</StackPanel>
</RelativePanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

As you may expect the buttons appear at the bottom of the page. I want the buttons to appear at the bottom of the screen.

Is there any kind of panels in XAML which I can use to implement:

```
====================
  Scrollable area

=====================
Button1       Button2
----------------------
```

1. a scrollable content area
2. and a panel below the scrollable area which sticks to the bottom of the screen and won't fly on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0">

        </ScrollViewer>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
        </StackPanel>   </Grid>
```

Hope this helps you. Please mark it as answer if it helped you.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. the buttons still appear at the bottom of the page

Comment: What do you mean by bottom of the page and not bottom of the screen ??

Comment: Let's size the windows size is 1920x1080. but the actual content is 1920x2000.

the buttons here appear above the 2000. But what i want to achieve that it appears right before the 1080 and keep doing so while I scroll to the bottom of the page

Comment: maybe you can try and span the page to the full window size.